# Removing duplicates between multiple large CSV files

Tags: python-3.x, duplicates

I am trying to find the best way to remove duplicates from large CSV files.
I receive CSV files of around 5/6 million rows every month.
I need to adjust these (I only need some of the columns, and I need to add some others).
The files also contain a lot of duplicate, and incomplete rows.

I've come up with a solution in python where I use a set and check for each row if it's in the set. And change what needs changing.

Now, I get the second file, and it contains a lot of duplicates that are in the previous file.

I'm trying to find an efficient solution to remove duplicates within the file, and between the different files. In the end I want to have a list (table or csv file) that contains only the new entries for that month.

I would like use python, and I was thinking about using a sqlite database for storing the data. But I'm unsure which way would be most efficient.

Comment: pandas `drop_duplicates` is there if you could load your csv into Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [numpy.unique()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.vstack((np.loadtxt("path/to/file1.csv"), np.loadtxt("path/to/file2.csv")))
#this will stack both arrays on top of each other, creating one giant array

data = np.unique(data, axis=0)
```

`np.unique` takes the entire array and returns only the unique elements. Make sure you set `axis=0` so that it goes row by row and not cell by cell.

One caveat: This should work, but if there are several million rows, it may take a while. Still better than doing it by hand though! Good luck!